# Get Span ID of clicked control in Repeater using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a repeater with items that each contain a video. This video name is dynamic and i embed into flowplayer from the ID in a span tag. My problem is i cant come up with logic that will only grab the selected span ID as each of the spans have the same parent ID, so it always grabs the first one.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_WebinarsCompleted" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rep_WebinarsCompleted_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="" id="overlay-triggers" name="overlay-triggers" runat="server">
            <span id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VideoFileName")%>'>View</span>
        </a>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I retrieve the span ID(video file name) from: var i = $("#overlay-triggers span").attr("id"),

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#overlay-triggers").overlay(
            onBeforeLoad: function () {
               var i = $("#overlay-triggers span").attr("id"),
               alert(i);
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ID's should be unique. No two elements on a page should have the same ID. Use a class instead. Also jQuery's `.each()` method might come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `onclick` to each of the spans.

So something like this:

```
<span onclick="spanClicked(this.id);" id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VideoFileName")%>'>View</span>
```

The `this.id` in the function call passes the span's (`this`) ID (`id`) property into the function. And have a function to call:

```
function spanClicked(id){
   alert(id);
}
```